# Trouble setting float variables in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm having some difficulty setting some floats and reading them. Here is a [a link to the application](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gyim8xvo29bf0ig/Gas%20Calc%202.zip) (and yes some parts are incomplete that I haven't got to yet).

If you download it you'll see the setter isn't working the way it should, unless I'm not doing it right.

Here is the code:

```
CalcViewController *CVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    float tempGasPrice;
    GasPrices *tempPrices;

    tempGasPrice = [[unleadedField text] floatValue];
    [tempPrices setUnleaded:tempGasPrice];
    NSLog(@"%F", tempPrices.unleaded);

    tempGasPrice = [[premiumField text] floatValue];
    [tempPrices setPremium:tempGasPrice];
    NSLog(@"%F", tempPrices.premium);

    tempGasPrice = [[superGasField text] floatValue];
    [tempPrices setSuperGas:tempGasPrice];
    NSLog(@"%F", tempPrices.superGas);
```

This is the part I need help with, if I input 1 into the text field for unleadedField, premiumField, or superGasField I want the NSLog to output 1 but instead it outputs 0.

Comment: You never call `alloc/init...` on your `tempPrices` variable. You need to create an object instance before you can use it.

Comment: What rmaddy said, and use %f to output it, not %F.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe that it was so simple a fix v.v

Answer (score -4):

float tempGasPrice;

```
tempGasPrice = [[self.txtField text] floatValue];


NSLog(@"%F", tempGasPrice);
```

try this..

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to do in the code. The NSLog was to see what was being stored.